# Remember if checkbox checked across multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox in each page of my website that toggles dark mode, but if it is checked (dark mode enabled) and I change pages, the page defaults to lite mode. I was wondering if it would be possible to set it up so that it will remember if the checkbox was checked and automatically check it on the new page, it would also be nice to have it remember so if you close the site and reopen it it well be on the mode you selected previously but that is not 100% necessary

```html
<!-- checkbox -->

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle" class="togglebtn">
     <i id="toggle-img" class="fa-solid fa-moon"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for this using JavaScript.  ``localStorage`` means even after browser is closed, and user again came to your website, you website will have access to used state(in your case dark or lite mode) that user left with.

Answer (score 0):

this code:

```js
function getFromStorage() {
  document.querySelector('#toggle').checked = localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') === 'true'
}

document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
  localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', JSON.stringify(target.checked))
})

window.addEventListener("storage", getFromStorage)
getFromStorage()
```